# Updating multiple row

Tags: mysql, sql

In the database I have a table that has tons of information. What I'm trying to do it set a limit where a number and figure are the same. I think I'm on the right track but I'm missing something. Anyone have an idea?

```
UPDATE loc l
SET l.limit = (SELECT (lo.factor*j.limit)
                FROM (SELECT limit, num, fig FROM loc WHERE typ = 'WE') j, loc lo
                WHERE lo.typ = 'TR'  
                AND lo.num = j.num    
                AND lo.fig = j.fig )
WHERE l.typ = 'WE'
```

Comment: use join instead of subqueries

Comment: not to good with joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `join`.  But you are taking the correlated subquery approach.

I suspect the problem is that your subquery is not correlated to the outer query.  You need to remove the `loc` table in the subquery:

```
UPDATE loc l
  SET l.`limit` = (SELECT (lo.factor*j.`limit`)
                   FROM (SELECT `limit`, num, fig
                         FROM loc
                         WHERE typ = 'WE'
                        ) j
                   WHERE l.typ = 'TR' AND
                         l.num = j.num  AND
                         l.fig = j.fig
                  )
   WHERE l.typ = 'WE';
```

In addition, `limit` is a reserved word.  You shouldn't use it as a column name.  Because you are, you need to put it in backticks or double quotes.

Comment: Thanks but the limit is the name of the table, not my choice, I tried this one but it's giving me a missing expression error.

Comment: Nope I was wrong, I hit the ' instead of ` so the error was on me, thanks this works great.